# npm cannot find node on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, maven, npm

When I try to build a project with Maven, which calls npm, it fails with such an error message:

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! code 1
[ERROR] npm ERR! path C:\(path to some node module)
[ERROR] npm ERR! command failed
[ERROR] npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/install.js
[ERROR] npm ERR! 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[ERROR] npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
```

The `node` program is normally present and available from the same terminal. What can cause such an error?

Answer (score 0):

A npm ERR! code 1 usually occurs when npm fails to install a node module. Check the latest version for your module, update it in package.json and run
`npm install` again. If this doesn't work, you can downgrade your version of npm to a more stable one and try again.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change project dependencies. The projects builds successfully on Jenkins and on Mac computers so I'd like to build it on a Windows computer, too.

Comment: Have you checked your PATH variable for any discrepancies?